# Android: Check if TTS voice data package is installed

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am using Text-To-Speech in my app. It works fine, when the voice data package is installed. However, when no voice data is installed and I call the following method, than no audio is played:

```
_textToSpeech.speak( text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null );
```

Therefore I want to check if the package is installed to give the user a notification, but I found no way to do this.
The class "TextToSpeech" provides a method "isLanguageAvailable()". But if voice data is installed or not installed, the result of the method is always the same.

```
_textToSpeech.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.GERMANY) // result is 1 (LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE)

_textToSpeech.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.GERMAN) // result is 0 (LANG_AVAILABLE)
```

In my android settings the preferred TTS engine is 'Google Text-to-speech'.

Has anyone a clue how to check if TTS voice data is installed?

Thanks..

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: so happy to finally find this question since I'm having the same problem... but then so annoying that there is no answer.  If I figure it out I will definitely answer.  For now, all I can think of is using a setUtteranceProgressListener and testing for an error... but this seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: Anybody else has decided this issue? I have installed Google TTS on my phone but TTS doesn't work. I need to sound Russian sentences.

Comment: I have solved the issue. On my phone was using default TTS by Pico TTS. I changed it to Google TTS and fix the problem. You have to go to settings -> Language and Input (язык и ввод) -> Speech (голосовой ввод) -> Speech synthesis (синтез речи). You have to install google tts preliminary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach which I used to check if the voice data is available or not.

```
private val ttsCheckCode = 1000

// Check by launching intent whether TTS is available or not
val checkIntent = Intent()
checkIntent.action = TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA
startActivityForResult(checkIntent, ttsCheckCode)
```

This will check whether the voice data is available or not. Check the documentation in android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech for more clarity. The above code will either give me CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS or CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FAIL. Once I receive CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS as result, I can do my operations like initialization, etc. in onActivityResult().

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == ttsCheckCode) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            // success, create the TTS instance and do other things
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.